# Word for an antonym with a negative connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to remember a word which describes an antonym which has an unnecessary negative connotation.

When I try to remember it I think of a word similar to 'dysphemistic' in terms of the letters used and the syllables, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Well 'dysphemism' is a word. Are you sure you aren't remembering that?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Wow. I answered my own question in the very text. Unbelievable. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*dysphemism*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dysphemism)

> noun
>
> 1. the substitution of a harsh, disparaging, or unpleasant expression for a more neutral one.
> 2. an expression so substituted.